# Animate with color blink new item added into ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-animation

There is a list and user can add items to this list. When he adds the item, the sort logic is implemented so it's not easy to see the newly added items.

I would like to animate newly added item so it's background changes with fade in/out effect when it's been added to the list.

What is the best approach to find such item and to do this?

Note: about "best approach to find new item" means that comparing old and new list seems like it will take too long and will create a visual delay in displaying newly added listview item.

Comment: It would be good if you use `RecycleView`. Check this https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators

Comment: @PiyushGupta It would be great to have such lib for the `ListView`

Comment: Its not outdated. But `RecycleView` is better than `ListView`. It was my suggestion.

Comment: what kind of adapter are you using?

Comment: @0X0nosugar I am using `ArrayAdapter<T>`

Comment: You know, it's a bit difficult guessing what you do to add your new items. I have some experience with animations for ListView rows (checked rows in multiple choice mode, which is similar because being checked should not be reflected in the underlying data). I'd like to have something small to experiment on, to be sure there are no misunderstandings about what you are trying to achieve.(cont)

Comment: If you don't have the time for that now I can only say that I'd try overriding "add()" to start the animation and set some tag to some View in the row, and onAnimationEnd I'd change that tag. "getView()" would have to cancel animations according to the tag to avoid animated Views being recycled.

Comment: @0X0nosugar Actually, I am passing a `List<T>` to Adapter's constructor and the list is being filled from the API via the Volley library. I do not use `add()` method.

Comment: OK, I don't know the Volley library (yet). So I don't know how not to interfere with what it's doing. Modifying "getView()" is essential to my approach, because your user would have to be able to scroll both during and after animations, and recycled animated rows are not so nice. So I hope someone else has an idea.